# Получив на вход некоторое натуральное число X, этот алгоритм печатает одно число. Сколько существует чисел Х, для которых алгоритм напечатает 243?

Tags: python

```
x = int(input()) 
s = 5 * (x // 10) 
n = 1 
while s < 300: 
    s = s + 28 
    n = n * 3 
print(n)
```

Comment: Ничего-то этот код не напечатает, кроме сообщения об ошибке компиляции...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замечаем, что если `x > 600`, то в цикл мы даже не зайдем и делаем перебор чисел от 1 до 600 (я взял больше, на всякий случай) и считаем сколько раз `n` принимает значение 243.
**Вот код:**

```
counter = 0
for x in range(1,10000):
    s = 5 * (x // 10) 
    n = 1 
    while s < 300: 
        s = s + 28 
        n = n * 3 
    if(n==243):
        counter+=1
print(counter)
```

**Output:** 60

Comment: Чел, который оставил минус, хотяб скажи, что я делаю не так. Почему ты минус поставил?

Comment: я не ставил минус

Comment: я хотел наоборот похвалить

Comment: но голоса участников с репутацией меньше 15 не учитываются

Comment: @George да я не тебе, просто кто-то минус кликнул, такое с репутацией >125? ну да ладно, рад что смог помочь :D

Comment: ещё раз спасибо, но это только начало

Comment: ещё два задания, которые очень странные

Answer (score 1):

для начала определим какое x максимально, для которого s будет вычисляться:

```
300 > 5 * [x/10]
60 > [x/10]
x < 600
```

теперь по самому код -

если код

```
while s < 300: 
    s = s + 28 
    n = n * 3 
    print(n)
```

тогда ответ **379**

если код

```
while s < 300: 
    s = s + 28 
    n = n * 3 
print(n)
```

тогда ответ **60**

Проверить можно написав программку:

```
counter = 0

for x in range(1, 600):
    s = 5 * (x // 10)
    n = 1

    while s < 300:
        s = s + 28
        n = n * 3

        counter += 1 if n == 243 else 0

print(counter)
```

**Касательно первого варианта можно определить теоретически кол-во:**

Необходимо чтобы цикл прокрутился минимум 5 раз - `243 = 3^5`,

значит s должно увеличиться минимум на `4 * 28 = 112`,

а значит стартовая s должна быть не более, чем `s = 300 - 112 = 188`,

откуда находим максимальное x: `188 < 5 * [x / 10]`

откуда `x = 379`

**Касательно второго варианта можно определить теоретически кол-во:**

рассуждения аналогичны предыдущим, но тут нам требуется СТРОГО 5 циклов, откуда находим диапазон для s: `[160-188)`

откуда x в диапазоне `[320-379]` т.е. 60 штук

Comment: `counter += 1 if n == 243 else 0`  можно записать так: `counter += n == 243`

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: @n1tr0xs, да, с++нотое наследие мешает иногда писать более коротко :)

Comment: @George, я в ответе добавил как теоретически это вычислить без кода

Comment: ну я просто удивлён, ты случаем не учитель?